# How to skip to next iteration in jQuery.each() util?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through an array of elements. jQuery's documentation says:

[jquery.Each() documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each#objectcallback)

> Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop, it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

I've tried calling 'return non-false;' and 'non-false;' (sans return) neither of which skip to the next iteration. Instead, they break the loop. What am i missing?

Comment: In their infinite wisdom, the bods at jQuery have now removed this note from the documentation - or at least, it's not in the [page for each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/). So I'm very glad to see this question can still be found here on SO, and by extension on Google, as this is one of those simple things I always forget :)

Answer (score 827, accepted):

What they mean by non-false is:

```
return true;
```

So this code:

```js
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
$.each(arr, function(i) {
  if (arr[i] == 'three') {
    return true;
  }
  console.log(arr[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

will log `one`, `two`, `four`, `five`.

Comment: To exit only current iteration it's enough just to return 'return'. And to  exit all iterations forward return false.

Comment: Its worth saying that this works because you are within a function when this code is executed.

Comment: when i do return (arr[i] === 'three'); why it is not working??

Comment: To me, non-false mean, you can return anything except return false;

Answer (score 62):

By 'return non-false', they mean to return any value which would not work out to boolean false.  So you could return `true`, `1`, `'non-false'`, or whatever else you can think up.

Comment: why not just for explicities sake " return 'continue';"

Comment: what about continue;? that worked in a variation of C sharp I worked with so I'm only guessing it'd have a similar effect in JS

Comment: @Brandito It isn't running like a normal loop - it is calling a function recursively, so in order for the loop to continue you need to end the processing inside the function.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript sort of has the idea of 'truthiness' and 'falsiness'. If a variable has a value then, generally 9as you will see) it has 'truthiness' - null, or no value tends to 'falsiness'. The snippets below might help:

```
var temp1; 
if ( temp1 )...  // false

var temp2 = true;
if ( temp2 )...  // true

var temp3 = "";
if ( temp3 ).... // false

var temp4 = "hello world";
if ( temp4 )...  // true
```

Hopefully that helps?

Also, its worth checking out these videos from Douglas Crockford

update: thanks @cphpython for spotting the broken links - I've updated to point at working versions now

[The Javascript language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M)

[Javascript - The Good Parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DKkVvOt6dk)

Comment: Links are broken... Btw, `0` is also a falsy value and the negation of it is truthy (and vice-versa to any other number, e.g. `!-42 === false`).

Answer (score 5):

The loop *only* breaks if you return literally `false`. Ex:

```
// this is how jquery calls your function
// notice hard comparison (===) against false
if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {
   break;
}
```

This means you can return anything else, including `undefined`, which is what you return if you return nothing, so you can simply use an empty return statement:

```
$.each(collection, function (index, item) {
   if (!someTestCondition)
      return; // go to next iteration

   // otherwise do something
});
```

It's possible this might vary by version; this is applicable for jquery 1.12.4. But really, when you exit out the bottom of the function, you are also returning nothing, and that's why the loop continues, so I would expect that there is no possibility whatsoever that returning nothing could *not* continue the loop. Unless they want to force everyone to start returning something to keep the loop going, returning nothing *has* to be a way to keep it going.

Answer (score 4):

Dont forget that you can sometimes just fall off the end of the block to get to the next iteration:

```
$(".row").each( function() {
    if ( ! leaveTheLoop ) {
        ... do stuff here ...
    }
});
```

Rather than actually returning like this:

```
$(".row").each( function() {
    if ( leaveTheLoop ) 
        return; //go to next iteration in .each()
    ... do stuff here ...
});
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but this is painfully horrible design. I mean... I've done it, in my 2 first years of college, when I didn't know better (even then I didn't like it), but it's not something that should be adviced...

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz, I hear you, but we disagree. The choice to not have a return statement may not be something you like. But I would submit that its a like/dislike thing rather than a good/bad thing. Neither has clear advantages objectively.

Comment: this has the disadvantage of increasing nesting