# jQuery each() restriction

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to restrict where it looks for the certain text?

```
$(data,'table tr').each(function(){

});
```

Is what I have right now. Am I any where near right?

Comment: can you expand on what you are trying to do? you code is iterating through all rows in "data" where data is a DOM object

Answer (score 2):

See [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) (aka the `$()` function) and see the supported forms.

It would likely be `$(selector, context)` where `context` is "A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery".

Alternatively, create a jQuery object and then apply the appropriate [traversing function(s)](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Happy coding.

Comment: that's one of those things I know, but never think of using for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for: [How to skip to next iteration in jQuery.each() util?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481601/how-to-skip-to-next-iteration-in-jquery-each-util/481611#481611)

```
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
$.each(arr, function(i) {
    if(arr[i] == 'three') {
        return true;
    }
    alert(arr[i]);
});
```

You can check certain conditions on the `tr`, like, does it have children? And if so, skip to the next iteration.