# How to use continue in jQuery each() loop?

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

In  my application i am using AJAX call. I want to use `break` and `continue` in this jQuery loop.

```
$('.submit').filter(':checked').each(function() {

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip to next iteration in jQuery.each() util?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481601/how-to-skip-to-next-iteration-in-jquery-each-util)

Comment: Answer can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481601/how-to-skip-to-next-iteration-in-jquery-each-util

Answer (score 587):

We can *break* both a `$(selector).each()` loop and a `$.each()` loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return `false`. Returning `non-false` is the same as a continue statement in a `for` loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

```
return false; // this is equivalent of 'break' for jQuery loop

return;       // this is equivalent of 'continue' for jQuery loop
```

---

Note that `$(selector).each()` and `$.each()` are **different** functions.

References:

- [$(selector).each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [What is the difference between $.each(selector) and
  $(selector).each()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611190/what-is-the-difference-between-eachselector-and-selector-each)

Comment: Although true, this doesn't seem to be documented. Is this an 'unofficial' feature?

Comment: It is documented here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ @MichaelScheper

Comment: That's the first place I looked, of course. I see it now; it kinda gets lost amongst all the examples.

Comment: return true; is also equivalent to continue.

Answer (score 51):

```
$('.submit').filter(':checked').each(function() {
    //This is same as 'continue'
    if(something){
        return true;
    }
    //This is same as 'break'
    if(something){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

return or return false are not the same as continue.  If the loop is inside a function the remainder of the function will not execute as you would expect with a true "continue".

Answer (score 8):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration. -- *[jQuery.each() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)*